# Removing duplicate results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, view

I have a view with some records, many of them are duplicated. I need to filter records and get only one from each of them.

I've tried with

```
SELECT TOP 1 Item, Code, Desc, '1' AS Qty FROM vwTbl1 WHERE Code = '12' OR Code = '311'
```

Also tried with DISTINCT but still I get all records.

but in this case it shows me only one record. Grouping by Code doesn't work.
Is there any other way how to solve this?

```
    Item | Code   | Desc | QTY
```

---

```
 a       |   12   |  1   |1
 a       |   311  |  2   |1
 b       |   12   |  3   |1
 b       |   311  |  4   |1
 c       |   1    |  5   |1
```

Reult should be like:

```
    Item | Code   | Desc | QTY
```

---

```
 a       |   12   |  1   |1
 b       |   311  |  3   |1
```

So for each criteria get the first record.

Comment: Specify your sample data and expected result

Comment: Why are you using `TOP 1` if you want multiple records?

Comment: I thought that with TOP 1 I will get only one record for each critieria (one record where Code = 12 and one record from Code = 311)

Answer (score 1):

The typical way of doing this uses `row_number()`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Item, Code, Desc, 1 AS Qty
FROM (SELECT v.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as seqnum
      FROM vwTbl1 
      WHERE Code IN ('12', '311') -- don't use single quotes if these are numbers
     ) v
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Still prints out 1 record.

Comment: @Josef  . . . Presumably, then, only one of the codes is in the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Top 1 *
FROM 
(
  SELECT Item, Code, Desc, '1' AS Qty 
  FROM vwTbl1 WHERE Code = '12' OR Code ='311'
)A

Edited Code based on your expected result:

Declare @YourTable table (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),Item varchar(50),Code INT,       
_Desc INT,Qty INT)
 Insert into @YourTable
 SELECT 'a',12,1,1 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'a',311,2,1 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'b',12,3,1 UNION ALL
 SELECT  'b',311,4,1 UNION ALL
 SELECT  'c',1 ,5 ,1   

 SELECT Item ,A.Code , _Desc ,Qty
 FROM @YourTable T
 JOIN 
 (
  SELECT MAX(Id) Id, Code FROM @YourTable GROUP BY Code
 )A ON A.Id = T.Id
```

Comment: Stil prints out only 1 record

Comment: You must specify your sample data and expected result then only others will provide answers easily

Comment: In your post Expected output is in correct vaues..? Because top 1 from each criteria means 'b'  is code values also 12.Check and update correct post

Comment: It is correct output because each item can hold same codes. I my output example Item A contains code 12 but also Item B contains code 12, but I need only one Item that contains code 12.

Comment: I updated My post.Try this is it satisfy your result or not